# CakePHP based application installation error: 777 permission directory is not writable?

Tags: permissions, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4, selinux

Trying to install my CakePHP based application on server, but got following error:

```
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /var/www/html/cakephp-2460/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 325

Warning: /var/www/html/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable
```

Sounds simple, but it is not - because my 'persistent' directory **IS writable** - in fact, /tmp and it's sub directories are writable.

Can you point me where is the problem? Do I missing some of PHP modules on server, or something like that?

Is there something to do with SeLinux?

Comment: What does tell 'sealert' or what does contain /var/log/audit/audit.log after you try to write something into /var/www/html/... ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user group for that directory is correct.

Maybe the user owner group does not have root permissions and therefor cannot write.

you may need to do the following on your server:

chown root:root -R /path_to_cake/app/tmp

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the problem in your SeLinux.You have to set www/..path../tmp directory is a `httpd_cache_t` so opan your terminal and

1. list to see all `httpt_cache_t` in system

   ```
      # semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd
   ```
2. Set your www/.../tmp directory

   ```
      # semanage fcontext -a -t 'httpd_cache_t' 'www/..path../tmp(/.*)?'
      # restorecon -Rvvv /path/to/wwwroot/cache
   ```